# Proving a functional can be expressed as an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm stuck with the first part and not sure how to progress.

**Theorem.** Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\phi$ be a functional on $V$. Then there exist an inner product on $V$ and an element $\textbf{u} \in V$, such that
$$\phi(\textbf{v}) = \langle \textbf{v} | \textbf{u}\rangle \quad \text{for every} \ \ \textbf{v}\in V.$$

(a) Choose $\textbf{u}\in V$ such that $\phi(\textbf{u}) = 1$ and let $B$ be a basis for $\ker \phi$. Prove that $C = \{\textbf{u}\} \cup B$ is a basis for $V$.

So I'm not sure how part (a) is done.
I tried:
Let $\textbf{u} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ then $ \phi(\textbf{u}) = \langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}|\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\rangle = 1. $

Then let $\textbf{x} \in C$ so this implies $\textbf{x} = \textbf{u}$ or $\textbf{x} \in B \implies \phi(\textbf{x})=0$ or $1$.
Not sure how to progress.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: If you are trying to prove the theorem, then you cannot assume it. And $u$ is any vector such that $\phi(u)=1$, so giving specific example is not going to do anything, unless you are trying to see what happens in specific cases

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I copied the question down exactly as it was

Comment: Choose orthonormal base of $\left(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\right)$ (we know such exists). If $V^*$ denotes space of all linear forms from $V$ to $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists monomorphism $f:V\to V^*$, and if $\dim V < \infty$ then $f$ is also epimorphism, and therefore isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a): a set must have two properties in order to be a basis.  The first is that the set needs to be linearly independent; this is easy to show.  $B$ is linearly independent, and $\mathbf u$ is outside the span of $B$ (since $\mathbf u$ is not in the kernel of $\phi$).

The second is that the set must span all of $V$.  To that end, we want to show that every vector $v$ is a linear combination of some vector from the kernel (i.e. a linear combination of elements of $B$) and a multiple of $\mathbf u$.  In particular, note that any $\mathbf v \in V$ can be written as
$$
\mathbf v = [\mathbf v - \phi(\mathbf v)\mathbf u] + [\phi(\mathbf v) \mathbf u]
$$
It's clear that the second term is a multiple of $\mathbf u$, but why is the first an element of $\ker \phi$?

Instead of that approach, we could also demonstrate the second property by using the rank nullity theorem and noting that the number of elements in $\{\mathbf u \} \cup B$ matches the dimension of $V$.  This only works, however, if $V$ is finite dimensional.

For the rest of the exercise, we define our inner product in such a way that $\{\mathbf u\} \cup B$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why the first term is an element of $\ker \phi$. Is it because $\phi(\textbf{v} - \phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u}) = \langle \textbf{v}-\phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u}) | \textbf{u} \rangle = \langle \textbf{v} | \textbf{u}\rangle - \phi(\textbf{v})\langle \textbf{u} | \textbf{u}\rangle = 0$?  
But it seems that I'm assuming the result as @user160738 mentioned

Comment: You are indeed assuming the result.  Remember that you can split linear functionals in the same way that you split that inner product, though:
$$
\phi(\mathbf  v - \phi(\mathbf v) \mathbf u) =
\phi(\mathbf v) - \phi(\phi(\mathbf v) \mathbf u)
$$
Perhaps you could take it from there

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought of splitting up the sum: $\textbf{v} = \textbf{v} \implies \textbf{v} = \textbf{v} - \phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u} +\phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u}$ but I guess that comes down to experience

Comment: @Natash1 Well, why did you think of splitting up the sum
$$
\phi(\textbf{v} - \phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u}) = \langle \textbf{v}-\phi(\textbf{v})\textbf{u}) | \textbf{u} \rangle = \langle \textbf{v} | \textbf{u}\rangle - \phi(\textbf{v})\langle \textbf{u} | \textbf{u}\rangle = 0?
$$
the key is to understand that it's all the same tricks, really.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\dim V <\infty$ and let $F$ be a field ($\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$).
For every fixed $v\in V$ transformation $x\mapsto\langle x, v\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to K$ is some scalar product, is linear form on $V^*$. In fact, let $\Phi_v:V\to K$, $\Phi_v(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$ and $a,b\in K$, $\,\alpha,\beta\in V$ be arbitrary. Then $\Phi_v(a\alpha+b\beta)=\langle a\alpha+b\beta, v\rangle = a\langle\alpha,v\rangle+b\langle\beta,v\rangle=a\Phi_v(\alpha)+b\Phi_v(\beta)$. Therefore for any fixed $v$ $\Phi_v\in V^*$.

Next consider transformation $\Phi:V\to V^*$, $\Phi(v)=\langle \cdot, v\rangle=\Phi_v$.
Put $a,b\in K$, $\,\alpha,\beta\in V$.
$\Phi(a\alpha+b\beta)=\Phi_{a\alpha+b\beta}=\langle\cdot,a\alpha+b\beta\rangle=a\langle\cdot,\alpha\rangle+b\langle\cdot,\beta\rangle=a\Phi_\alpha+b\Phi_\beta=a\Phi(\alpha)+b\Phi(\beta)$, so $\Phi$ is linear. Let $v\in\ker\Phi$, then for every $x\in V$ $\langle x,v\rangle=0$, and in particular $\langle v,v\rangle=0$, so $\ker\Phi=\left\{0\right\}$.

Take $\mathcal{B}=\left\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\right\}$ to be orthonormal basis of $V$ and $\mathcal{B}^*=\left\{e_1^*,e_2^*,...,e_n^*\right\}$ basis of $V^*$, dual to $\mathcal{B}$ so that $e_i^*(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

$\Phi_{e_j}=\langle\cdot,e_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^na_{kj}e_k^*,\, j=1,...,n$,
and because $\mathcal{B}$ is orthonormal 
$\delta_{ij}=\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^na_{kj}e^*_k(e_i)=\sum_{k=1}^na_{kj}\delta_{ki}=a_{ij}.$

Therefore for $j=1,...,n \, \langle\cdot,e_j\rangle=e^*_j$.

Given $\varphi\in V^*$ assume that for every inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to K$ and for every $u\in V$ there exists $v\in V$ such that $\varphi(v)\neq\langle v,u\rangle$ , that means $\varphi$ doesn't belong to the image of $\Phi$, $\mathrm{im}\Phi\subsetneq V^*$, which means $\Phi$ is not an isomorphism, contradiction.

This is rather lengthy proof and obviously doesn't handle case when $dim V$ is infinite, but this result is pretty important in analyzing self adjoint operators